# how to change a specific word in a string to uppercase

Tags: java

Input: a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
Output: a QUICK brown fox jumps over a LAZY dog.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Homework? Also, what have you tried? Also, which word?

Comment: Actually a quite neat homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ConvertWordToUpperCase {
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
            String inputStr = "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
            String outputStr = "";

            String words[] = inputStr.split(" ");

            for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
            {
                String word = words[i];
                if(word.equalsIgnoreCase("quick") || word.equalsIgnoreCase("lazy"))
                {
                    word = word.toUpperCase();
                }
                outputStr += word;
                outputStr += " ";
            }
            System.out.println(outputStr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should try to compile your code! In Java You can't run operators just inside of the class body. -1 until you correct your answer.

Comment: It is still not compilable. Last `outputStr` should have `S` instead of `s`.

Comment: And it prints `aQUICKbrownfoxjumpsoveraLAZYdog` - no spaces.

Comment: hey, I had made that change earlier. That was my first edit.

Comment: check now.. it will work as required

Comment: To deserve +1 for the answer to a simple question, you should make your answer perfect. It should be perfectly formatted, for instance (now it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

There is not a readymade method in Java for such purpose, however you can create your own usedefined method, Please checkout following code.

```
public class ChangeWord
{
    private void upperCaseWord ( String str, String word )
    {
        if ( str.indexOf ( word ) != -1 ) // Checking the Existance of word
        {
            int strLen = str.length();
            int index = str.indexOf ( word );
            int length = word.length();
            word = word.toUpperCase();
            String part1 = str.substring ( 0 , index );
            String part2 = str.substring ( index + length );
            String finalStr = part1 + word + part2;
            System.out.println ( "Final Result : " + finalStr );
        }
    }


    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {
        ChangeWord cw = new ChangeWord();
        String str  = "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
        cw.upperCaseWord ( str, "quick" );
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java methods should not have the first letter uppercased.  Not following the conventions will make your programs harder to maintain.

Comment: opps... sorry just forgot it, I have edited my code. please check it. is it better now ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do this:

```
    List<String> wordsToUppercase = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "lazy",
            "quick" });

    String input = "a quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.";

    for (String word : wordsToUppercase) {
        input = input.replaceAll(word, word.toUpperCase());
    }

    System.out.println(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toUpperCase();` will make the entire string uppercase.  If you are looking for those specific words, your going to have to use a variation of `String.format() and .subString();`